# How to get the id from the custom category?

Tags: categories, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

How do i get the ID from the current custom taxonomy (category) the user is browsing?

It uses a custom post type called "products"
The categories are called "pcategories"

With normal categories i would get it like this:

```
<?php if ( is_category() )  
{  
    $cat= get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) );
    $cat_id = $cat->cat_ID;
    $categorytable = myrp_api_comparison_table( $category = $cat_id, $number = null, $visit_text = "Visit Text", $image_set = null, $custom_fields = null, $rating_categories = null, $return = false );
    if(empty($categorytable))
    {} else 
    {           
    echo $categorytable;
    } 
} 
?>
```

So how would i do this with custom taxonomies?

If i do:

`<pre><?php print_r($wp_query->query_vars); ?></pre>`

I get:

```
Array
(
[pcategory] => televisies
[error] => 
[m] => 0
[p] => 0
[post_parent] => 
[subpost] => 
[subpost_id] => 
[attachment] => 
[attachment_id] => 0
[name] => 
[static] => 
[pagename] => 
[page_id] => 0
[second] => 
[minute] => 
[hour] => 
[day] => 0
[monthnum] => 0
[year] => 0
[w] => 0
[category_name] => 
[tag] => 
[cat] => 
[tag_id] => 
[author_name] => 
[feed] => 
[tb] => 
[paged] => 0
[comments_popup] => 
[meta_key] => 
[meta_value] => 
[preview] => 
[s] => 
[sentence] => 
[fields] => 
[category__in] => Array
    (
    )

[category__not_in] => Array
    (
    )

[category__and] => Array
    (
    )

[post__in] => Array
    (
    )

[post__not_in] => Array
    (
    )

[tag__in] => Array
    (
    )

[tag__not_in] => Array
    (
    )

[tag__and] => Array
    (
    )

[tag_slug__in] => Array
    (
    )

[tag_slug__and] => Array
    (
    )

[ignore_sticky_posts] => 
[suppress_filters] => 
[cache_results] => 1
[update_post_term_cache] => 1
[update_post_meta_cache] => 1
[post_type] => 
[posts_per_page] => 10
[nopaging] => 
[comments_per_page] => 50
[no_found_rows] => 
[taxonomy] => pcategory
[term] => televisies
[order] => DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by using the following code:

```
$current_term = $wp_query->get_queried_object();    
$termid = $current_term->term_id;
```

Works quite well